# Handling delete event in pygtk/glade

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk, glade

I have a GUI designed in **glade**, using python/gtk in the background.I want to handle the `delete event` and display a "Are you sure?"-message dialog.I have been trying to handle the delete and destroy events, but failing to do so.any light?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import .... stuff




class App:
  def __init__(self):


    self.gladefile = 'test.glade'
    windowname = 'window'# This must match the window name in glade
    self.wTree = gtk.glade.XML(self.gladefile, windowname)# object for acessing widgets


    dic={
    # Also need to set project2's signal tab
       'on_window_delete_event':self.on_erro,
       'on_window_destroy_event':self.on_erro,
         }

    self.wTree.signal_autoconnect (dic)
    self.op=self.wTree.get_widget('window')
    self.op.show()

  def on_erro(self,widget,*args):

        print 'hello'






app = App()
gtk.main()
```

This code opens a simple window .On clicking on close button, it prints hello and exits.(I want the window to remain open)

Comment: What have you tried? How have you failed? Unless you elaborate, nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to return `True` in order to stop propagation of the delete event in the callback `on_erro` as mentioned in the [documentation for `"delete-event"`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-delete-event). In your current code, the callback is not returning any boolean value as required by the function, which I am guessing is returning `False` (Please check the signature for `on_window_delete_event` callback functions, the return type is boolean)
Hope this helps!